# Assigning and reusing that variable from if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following code in .haml file:

```
.row-fluid.page-header
  %h2 My Programs
  - if @program.students(:confirmed).first 
    - if !@program.students(:confirmed).first.fees_info['has_info']
      .alert.alert-danger
        We do not have your information on file!
```

This code is trying to print the alert message if we do not have the "has_info" flag set for a student enrolled in a program.

My question is, what is a better way to write the above two if statements.

I tried/wanted to assign a variable in the if statement, but could not get it to work: eg I tried:

```
- if first_record = @program.students(:confirmed).first
  - if first_record.fees_info['has_info']
```

But this did not work. How can I declare a variable which I can reuse in these if statements here?

Comment: Tin Man has it right, you're doing work in the view that doesn't belong there. This should be in a helper, or (my preference) a decorator, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this...

Put this code in the controller:

```
first_record = @program.students(:confirmed).first
@has_first_record_info = first_record && first_record.fees_info['has_info']
```

Put `@first_record_alert` in the view to replace the `if` statements:

```
- unless @has_first_record_info 
  .alert.alert-danger
    We do not have your information on file!
```

You want to show whether the student has a record and info, so test for that first. Then, in the view, you want to show an alert if their information doesn't exist, so use `unless` which is equivalent to `if !@has_first_record_info`.